# Code-First Development with Entity Framework 4 - How to using Sql server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

Ive been reading scott guthrie post about Code First Development using EF 4. post-> http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx

This post refer to the possibility to code first and then generate a dabatase using SQL Compact Edition and an sdf file.

I would like to know if its possible to use a SQL SERVER 2008 database with EF4 code first approach and what do I have to modify in my web.config file or other areas in my app in order to generate the database for 2008 instead of CE.

currently the example display a webconfig area with the following details:

```
<connectionStrings configSource="ConnectionStrings.config" />
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
        <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
        <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 4.0" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

Thanks in advance. brgds

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Look at this link where the example is using SQL Server 2008: [EF4 Code First Walkthrough](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/03/15/ef-4-1-code-first-walkthrough.aspx)

Comment: thank you so much!. Very clear about the connection string. I will use it in the same way I do with other apps. Additionally, do you know what do I have to do in order to generate the database? which command generates the db after I configure the connection string?. thanks in advance!

Comment: Look under Deployment Considerations in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh126815.aspx, a combination of config file and constructor in DbContext